# iOS: Add subview with a fix position on screen

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, position

How do I fix a subviews position on screen (especially in UIScrollView and UITableView)? I think in storyboard

```
[self.view addSubview:aSubView];
```

does not work anymore.

Any ideas?

**EDIT #1**: I am using a UITableViewController, not a simple UITableView.

**EDIT #2**:

```
CGRect fixedFrame = self.menuViewRelative.frame;
fixedFrame.origin.y = 0 + scrollView.contentOffset.y;
self.menuViewRelative.frame = fixedFrame;

menuViewRelative = [[UIView alloc] init];
menuViewRelative.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
menuViewRelative.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 50.0);

[self.view addSubview:self.menuViewRelative];
```

Comment: please flesh out your question a bit.... I dont get what you want to do.

Comment: in ios 6 u can use constraints in xib

Comment: I want to fix the position of a subview (UIView) so it is not scrolling with the content of a UITableView. The subview should stay fixed on screen..

Comment: You add the view that should not scroll as a sibling of the scrolling view. Suppose your scrollview or tableview is a child of view/window `XY`, simply add your fixed view as a subview of XY as well.

Comment: @Till: Sorry, I forgot to say that it's a UITableViewController :S Excuse me. Any idea anyway?

Comment: What prevents you from using a UITableView within a regular UIViewController?

Comment: @Till: Static Cells are only accepted in a UITableViewController.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As others noted, this would be a bit easier if you didn't use a `UITableViewController`, but it's not that hard anyway.

`UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, so table view's delegate (your `UITableViewController` instance in this case) will also receive `UIScrollViewDelegate` method calls. All you have to do is implement the method that gets called every time scroll offset changes and adjust the frame of your "fixed" view.

Something like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGRect fixedFrame = self.fixedView.frame;
    fixedFrame.origin.y = 20 + scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    self.fixedView.frame = fixedFrame;
}
```

Replace 20 by how many points you want it to be from top of the table view. You still add `self.fixedView` as a subliew of `self.view`, this will just make sure it looks like it's in a fixed position above table view.

---

**Edit:** with the code you posted, I'm guessing your verion should look like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    menuViewRelative = [[UIView alloc] init];
    menuViewRelative.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    menuViewRelative.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 50.0);

    [self.view addSubview:self.menuViewRelative];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    CGRect fixedFrame = self.menuViewRelative.frame;
    fixedFrame.origin.y = 0 + scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    self.menuViewRelative.frame = fixedFrame;
}
```

Comment: Tried this way, but it does not seem to work (please have a look at the code in my question above).

Comment: Where did you put that code? You should not have those other 4 lines in this method, they should stay in your viewDidLoad or where ever you had them. The method I posted *does* work, you just have to use it like I described.

Comment: Check out the edit to my answer, if you put it that way it will work.

Comment: I use this 4 lines in the same method, because I need to know when y < -50 to let the subview appear :S

Comment: Well you are doing it wrong. I answered your question, you should accept the right answer and if you have any additional questions ask them. I can't read your mind.

Comment: ok, it's working. But the separator lines scoll 'over' the frame. Is there a way to bring the frame in front of the TableView? I can't accept your answer if it's not working perfectly..

Comment: That should not be happening. Try `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.menuViewRelative];` inside `scrollViewDidScroll`.

Answer (score 3):

Can you just add your subview into the window, like:

```
[self.view.window addSubview:mySubView];
```

It works for me. I added a pix position info view in a dynamic table view.

Answer (score 0):

If its a simple view controller which contains a table view, [self.view addSubview:aSubView] should work. But if its a table view controller, it wont work.

Comment: Absolutely right. It is a UITableViewController.. but how can I fix the position of the subview anyway?

Comment: You cant. Use a simple UIViewController and add a UITableView as a sub view to it. Then follow the regular way of binding data source, populating data etc. Once this is done, you can use [self.view addSubview:view]

Comment: There could be work around to get a fixed positioned item inside a table view. But it is not advisable. Rather, fixing your view controller is the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, by moving sub (your) view from UIScrollView to super view of scrollview.

Here is simple example:

Place/set your button over scroll view (not inside scroll view) as shown here in this snapshot. And also set button constraints (position) with respect to super view of your scrollview.

[image]

Here is ref. snapshot of hierarchy of position of each view over each-other.

[image]